# iPad 4 Ambient light sensor

Tags: ipad

I hear the iPod Touch 5 dropped the ambient light sensor.  What about the new iPad 4? Does that device have an ambient light sensor and automatic brightness adjustment?

Comment: If you linked to where you heard this, perhaps it would be worth documenting a well spread misunderstanding. As it stands a search of the documentation answers this binary question quite well. As it doesn't invite someone t answer why, it's not a good fit for our Q&A site.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on the [tech specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) page, yes it still has an ambient light sensor, and [so does](http://www.apple.com/ipad-mini/specs/) the iPad Mini.